# Refresh to next page to prevent timeout concerns? Or after certain amount of queries?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipulate my mysql tables with PHP but when I update them via PHP I have trouble with time out concerns.

Is it possible to refresh or "start a new session" while continuing on from last session? So it doesn't time out? Or is it possible to somehow go to a new page to prevent time outs?

What's the best possible way can someone help me please?

Maybe switch over to a new page after 150 successful queries or after 10 seconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 seconds won't give you a time out usually...  i was interested myself how long a browser will time out usually, but you can try sleeping for 20 seconds and then 30 and more and see if your browser times out.

I have had a Rails server running on a local Macbook with many partials and query, and 45 seconds and the page won't time out.

If you don't need immediate feedback, you can put the task in a queue to be processed by cron job every 10 minutes or every 30 minutes depending on your need.

If you need immediate feedback and the task is exceeding long, you can break them down to a safe limit, and issue a redirect to a second and third page with param `task=1000`, `task=2000` and report so on the page.  Another way that might work is to fork a process and report an ID... and when the task is all done, near the end, update a SQL table that the task with that ID is done, and have a page display all finished task and that page can refresh every 10 seconds.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think of breaking it down into pieces. That's a pretty good idea. Thinking about it.... While I'm executing queries in my while statement do you think I could add a variable in there?

Comment: Edit: Add a variable in there and make it count the queries executed. Then after I reach 400, to start a new session and set the variable back to zero, so it loops and starts a new session after 400 queries?

Comment: yes you can do something like that... or something like `if (($i+1) % 400 == 0)` then do something...  note that sometimes the database server can be slower than usual, during busy time or if the machine hosts many websites and have multiple database servers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use set_time_limit() after successful query execution so you won't incur into timeout if everything is running ok.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php